# Rolling logs every 30 minutes

Tags: c++, configuration, log4j, log4cxx

I'm using log4cxx and with the following configuration, I understand I can roll a log every hour, minute, day and so on.

```
            <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
              <param name="FileNamePattern" value="loog.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log"/>
            </rollingPolicy>
```

How can I roll the logs every 30 minutes? What is the configuration for this? Can I do this via the configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do it without a change in the implementation (i.e. extending `TimeBasedRollingPolicy`, `RollingFileAppender` and maybe more). It's just how it works, rollover is done when the full unit (a day, hour, minute, etc.) changes. There's no way to specify more than one unit.